# Waiting boost asio's future lasts forever after io_service.stop()

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, boost, boost-asio

I try to wait on a `std::future` object which is returned from any `boost::asio::async_` function (with using `use_future`). For example:

```
auto endpoint_future = resolver.async_resolve(query, boost::asio::use_future);
endpoint_future.wait(); // lasts forever after io_service.stop();
```

This is done in one thread.
I have also another thread which is started before this `async_resolve` call:

```
runner_ = std::thread([this]() {
    boost::asio::io_service::work work(io_service_);
    io_service_.run();
});
```

Everything works pretty fine but later I also added a `boost::asio::deadline_timer` to stop any work with `io_service`:

```
void deadlineTimeout() {
    deadline_.cancel();
    io_service_.stop();
    // closing socket here does not work too
}
```

However, in `deadlineTimeout()` when deadline reaches it's timeout and it performs `io_service_.stop()` the future is not getting released so the `endpointer_future.wait()` still blocks. How can I stop waiting on the future in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Just found a solution by myself: we need not to `stop()` the `io_service` but `reset()` it and before this we need to close the socket, thus the correct timeout callback will be:

```
void deadlineTimeout() {
    deadline_.cancel();
    socket_.close(); // socket_ is a socket on io_service_
    io_service_.reset();
}
```

After this change all the futures are released.

Comment: `io_service::stop()` just sets a flag asking the service to stop "as soon as possible."   As long as you have the outstanding read on the socket the service can't stop, so the `socket_.close()` is the important part of your answer.

Comment: You are wrong. Closing socket and call io_service.stop() after does not work. Important here is to call reset() instead of stop().

Comment: calling reset() on an io_service that is still running is wrong.   You should shut it down cleanly.   reset is intended to be used if you plan to reuse the service after it has stopped.   http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/reset.html

Comment: You also need to remove the `work` before the service can stop.  (Reset does that by brute force (nasty))

Comment: The [reset()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/reset.html) documentation strictly forbids invoking `reset()` on the `io_service` while there are outstanding calls to `poll()`, `poll_one()`, `run()`, or `run_one()`.

Answer (score 2):

The call to `io_sevice.stop()` will cause all all invocations of `run()` and `run_one()` to return as soon as possible.  When invoked from within a handler, the caller will return from `run()` without invoking any additional handlers.  In your case, the `async_resolve`'s completion handler will set the `promise` associated with `endpoint_future`; however, by stopping the `io_service`, the completion handler will not be invoked.  Consider either:

- `cancel()` the I/O objects associated with the `future`, then continue running the `io_service` to completion so that the `promise`'s value gets set
- destroying all I/O objects, then destroying the `io_service` so that the handler is deleted and a broken promise is detected by the `future`
- loop performing a timed wait on the future, and exit the loop if the future is ready or if the `io_service` has been stopped.  For example, the following function returns a `boost::optional` with the value of the future or `boost::none` if the future will not be set.

  ```cpp
  template <typename T>
  boost::optional<T> get(
    boost::asio::io_service& io_service,
    std::future<T>& future)
  {
    for (;;)
    {
      // If the future is ready, get the value.
      if (future.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(1)) == std::future_status::ready)
      {
        return {future.get()};
      }
      // Otherwise, if the future is never going to be set, return none.
      if (io_service.stopped())
      {
        return {boost::none};
      }
    }
  }

  ...
  if (auto endpoint_iterator = get(io_service, endpoint_future))
  {
    // use *endpoint_iterator...
  }
  ```

---

Below is an example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/033904c18ac08058) how to safely wait on a future while stopping the `io_service`:

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/use_future.hpp>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

template <typename T>
boost::optional<T> get(
  boost::asio::io_service& io_service,
  std::future<T>& future)
{
  for (;;)
  {
    // If the future is ready, get the value.
    if (future.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(1)) == std::future_status::ready)
    {
      return {future.get()};
    }
    // Otherwise, if the future is never going to be set, return none.
    if (io_service.stopped())
    {
      std::cout << "io_service stopped, future will not be set" << std::endl;
      return {boost::none};
    }
    std::cout << "timeout waiting for future" << std::endl;
  }
}

int main()
{
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;

  // Create I/O objects.
  boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket(io_service,
    boost::asio::ip::udp::v4());
  boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(io_service);

  // Process the io_service in the runner thread.
  auto runner = std::thread([&]() {
    boost::asio::io_service::work work(io_service);
    io_service.run();
  });

  // Start an operation that will not complete.
  auto bytes_transferred_future = socket.async_receive(
    boost::asio::null_buffers(), boost::asio::use_future);

  // Arm the timer.
  timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(2));
  timer.async_wait([&](const boost::system::error_code&) {
    timer.cancel();
    socket.close();
    io_service.stop();
  });

  // bytes_transferred's promise will never be set as the io_service
  // is not running.
  auto bytes_transferred = get(io_service, bytes_transferred_future);
  assert(!bytes_transferred);

  runner.join();
}
```

Comment: Waiting with `wait_for` and checking something is useless overhead which I would like to avoid. I was thought about this solution but I try to find something more efficient which would just release all the futures I wait for without manual work. Is this possible to do correctly (without `reset` if it is wrong)?

Comment: @VictorPolevoy As far as I know, there are only 3 options with well defined behavior: run the handler; destroy the handler; or periodically wait for the handler.  It seems awkward to synchronously block indefinitely on an asynchronous operation that may never complete. If `wait_for()` or `wait_until()` are used, and the duration or time provided is slightly larger than the `deadline_timer`'s expiration, then it greatly reduces the chance of waiting multiple times on the future.

Answer (score 0):

Make the work visible to the deadline timeout and allow the deadline timeout to delete it.

```
boost::scoped_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work work;
```

You can still create the work here, but heap allocate it.

```
runner_ = std::thread([this]() {
    work = new boost::asio::io_service::work(io_service_);
    io_service_.run();
});
```

And shut down like this:

```
void deadlineTimeout() {
    deadline_.cancel();
    socket_.close(); // socket_ is a socket on io_service_
    work.reset();

    // The io_service::run() will exit when there are no active requests 
    // (i.e. no sockeet, no deadline, and no work)
    // so you do not need to call: io_service_.stop();
}
```

Comment: The call to `stop()` may have undesirable affects.  The internal completion handler for the cancelled `async_resolve` operation may never get invoked, resulting in the `std::promise` never having its value set.